# How can I use read.table in R properly with this database?

Tags: r, dataframe, clipboard, read.table

I'm trying to read this dummy database with `read.table(file="clipboard")` in R:

```
             Aspecto   Sexo      Ranking
1             Imagen   Hombre    7.50
2      Mantenimiento   Hombre    7.18
3               Otro   Hombre    7.05
4  Espacios de venta   Hombre    6.91
5         Vigilancia   Hombre    6.36
6             Tiempo   Hombre    6.51
7    Espacios libres   Hombre    6.40
8             Imagen   Mujer     7.21
9      Mantenimiento   Mujer     7.30
10              Otro   Mujer     6.90
11 Espacios de venta   Mujer     7.02
12        Vigilancia   Mujer     6.53
13            Tiempo   Mujer     6.40
14   Espacios libres   Mujer     5.78
```

This code seems to work:

```
pw <- read.table(file="clipboard", dec=".", sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

But the structure is clearly something I don't want:

```
str(pw)
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Aspecto...Sexo......Ranking: Factor w/ 14 levels "1
```

I've tried many things including `fill=TRUE` and so other arguments but I just can't get what I expect. For example:

```
pw <- read.table(file="clipboard", dec=".", sep="", header=TRUE)
Error in read.table(file = "clipboard", dec = ".", sep = "", header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no way for R to understand that `Espacios de venta` is part of same column whereas `Imagen   Hombre ` are part of different columns. How is the data stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read.fwf`, since the columns have fixed widths and you don't have quotes surrounding character strings. And since the first row has only 3 names, we skip this, but read them in later using scan.

```
clipboard <- read.fwf("clipboard.txt", widths=c(2,18,9,8), skip=1, as.is=TRUE) 
# or row.names=1 to ignore the first un-named column

colnames(clipboard)[2:4] = scan("clipboard.txt", what=rep("character", 3), nlines=1)

str(clipboard)

'data.frame':   14 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ V1     : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Aspecto: chr  "            Imagen" "     Mantenimiento" "              Otro" " Espacios de venta" ...
 $ Sexo   : chr  "   Hombre" "   Hombre" "   Hombre" "   Hombre" ...
 $ Ranking: num  7.5 7.18 7.05 6.91 6.36 6.51 6.4 7.21 7.3 6.9 ...
```

Comment: Never heard nor read about read.fwf. Thank you so much for this lesson!